# Как автоматизировать код для калькулятора сна?

Tags: javascript, html

**Как автоматизировать код для калькулятора сна?**
Смотрите, есть идея сделать калькулятор, который вычисляет фазы сна человека (когда ему лучше всего проснуться) (ниже приведен пример его логики и работы)
Но есть проблема! Я попробовал написать код и понял, что если каждый раз по одной минуте рассчитывать время на засыпания, то получится оочень длинный и не практичный код! Можете пожалуйста помочь в автоматизации кода (можно ли через циклы или что-то подобное) упростить его?

**Логика работы калькулятора сна.**
Во сне человек проходит несколько циклов из поочередно чередующихся медленной и быстрой фаз сна. Если проснуться в период медленной фазы, то будет ощущение недосыпания и разбитости, чего можно избежать, проснувшись в конце быстрой фазы сна.

Каждая фаза сна длится в среднем 90 минут, а чтобы взрослый человек полноценно выспался необходимо 5-6 таких фаз, что соответствует 7-9 часам сна.

**Пример 1.** Если Вам нужно проснуться в максимально хорошем самочувствии в 7:30 утра, то укажите в калькуляторе Время пробуждения "07:30". В результате получится 6 фаз (22:30, 00:00, 01:30, 03:00, 04:30 и 06:00), к которым Вы должны уснуть.

Как было указано выше, чтобы поспать рекомендуемые для большинства 7-9 часов, необходимо уснуть в 1-ом или во 2-ом цикле в 22:30 и 00:00 соответственно. Более того, даже если Вы уснете, например, в 4-ой фазе к 04:30 или 5-ой, то легче проснетесь к 7:30.

**Пример 2.** Вам нужно узнать, во сколько часов лучше проснуться, если Вы засыпаете в 23:40, для чего в онлайн калькуляторе указываете Время засыпания "23:40". По результату расчета получим следующие фазы 08:40, 07:10, 05:40, 04:10, 02:40, 01:10.

Это времена, на которые лучше всего ставить будильник, чтобы максимально выспаться и проснуться в бодром состоянии.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
 <style>
    .timepicker{
        background: none;
        border: none;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
 </style>
 
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
         <div class="col s12 m6">
             <form>
                 <div class="input-field">
                     <input type="button" class="timepicker" value="06:00">
                     <!-- <label for="time">Set Time</label> -->
                     <p id="indicator"></p>
                     <p id="time"></p>
                     <p id="time2"></p>
                     <p id="time3"></p>
                     <p id="time4"></p>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
         <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <button onclick="func()">Кнопка</button>
 
 <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     var elems = document.querySelector('.timepicker');
     var instances = M.Timepicker.init(elems,{
        //  showClearBtn:true
            twelveHour:false
     });
   });
 
   function time(){
    document.querySelector('#indicator').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.timepicker').value
   }
   setInterval(time, 100)
   function func(){ //вот этот кусок кода нужно как-то автоматизировать, а не делать это по каждой минуте
   var indicator = document.querySelector('#indicator')
   if (indicator.innerHTML == '00:00'){
    document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML = '23:30'
    document.querySelector('#time2').innerHTML = '01:00'
    document.querySelector('#time3').innerHTML = '02:30'
    document.querySelector('#time4').innerHTML = '04:00'
   }
   if (indicator.innerHTML == '00:01'){
    document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML = '23:31'
    document.querySelector('#time2').innerHTML = '01:01'
    document.querySelector('#time3').innerHTML = '02:31'
    document.querySelector('#time4').innerHTML = '04:01'
   }
   if (indicator.innerHTML == '00:02'){
    document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML = '23:32'
    document.querySelector('#time2').innerHTML = '01:02'
    document.querySelector('#time3').innerHTML = '02:32'
    document.querySelector('#time4').innerHTML = '04:02'
   }
}
 
 </script>
 
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вас интересует только сама логика, поэтому убрал все украшательства. Также, чтобы сократить код, для вывода промежуточных значений использовались однотипные элементы (в данном случае `<input>`).

Количество фаз может быть любым (т.е. достаточно просто добавить/удалить строчки с `<label>` и `<input>`), но нужно помнить, что каждая соседняя фаза будет отличаться ровно на указанный интервал (есть комментарий в коде).

Конкретно в данном решении, есть привязка к типу поля ввода (здесь `type="time"`), но это можно менять в соответствии задачей. Главное, чтобы первое и последнее поле были одинакового типа, но отличались от промежуточных.

Если сделан выбор в первом поле ("Время засыпания"), то интервалы рассчитываются от введённого значения с инкрементом. Для поля "Время пробуждения" логика аналогична, но интервалы отнимаются. Код интерактивен - все изменения отображаются сразу:

```js
const FORM = document.querySelector('form');
FORM.querySelector('#sleep').addEventListener('input', fCalc);
FORM.querySelector('#wake').addEventListener('input', fCalc);

function fCalc() {
  let dNow = new Date();
  let sTime = this.value.split(':');
  dNow.setHours(+sTime[0]);
  dNow.setMinutes(+sTime[1]);
  let aTrip = [...FORM.querySelectorAll(`input:not([id=${this.id}])`)];
  let nDir = (aTrip[0].type == 'time' && -1) || 1;
  if (nDir < 0) aTrip.reverse();
  aTrip.forEach((el) => {
    dNow.setMinutes(dNow.getMinutes() + 90 * nDir); // 90 - продолжительноть фазы в минутах
    el.value = `${dNow.getHours()}`.padStart(2, '0') + ':' + `${dNow.getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, '0');
  });
}
```

```css
form { margin: 0 auto; width: max-content; }
label, input { margin: .05em; border: none; font: 16px/1.4em sans-serif; }
label { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; gap: .5em; }
input { width: 5em; padding: 0 .05em; }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Время засыпания <input type="time" id="sleep"></label>
  <label>1-я фаза <input readonly></label>
  <label>2-я фаза <input readonly></label>
  <label>3-я фаза <input readonly></label>
  <label>4-я фаза <input readonly></label>
  <label>5-я фаза <input readonly></label>
  <label>Время пробуждения <input type="time" id="wake"></label>
</form>
```